# how to gather results from survey in console?

Tags: jquery

I'm quickly making this little survey where people have to review my website by giving it a grade from 1 to 10. I have 1 question and 10 radio buttons (each representing a number on 10) per row, and 3 questions in total. I want to know that once people choose their grades (for example, first question they respond with 1/10, second 5/10, and third 10/10) and click submit, how do I make sure their results get saved in console.log. I will have multiple people taking the 'survey', so many results will need to be saved. I need to know what the jquery would look like.

Comment: `console.log` is a **client**-side log. Only the computer where the person gives the rating will store the results. You'd be far better off with a database.

Comment: @ObsidianAge good advice but not entirely correct about it being client-side only ~ https://nodejs.org/api/console.html

Comment: While it's true that Node.js can use `console.log` to store on the server, you'd still need access to that server's terminal. Also, while possible, it's unlikely that this question was talking about Node :) For what it's worth, it's also possible that the computer in question is more of a showcase kiosk, where local storage would be adequate. Regardless of environment, effort is still expected. Please update your question to show what you have already tried, stating a specific problem you face. For further information, please take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: It will be on my own laptop, which I will be taking around classes for people to do the survey. It's a school project; I won't even publish the thing. You got it right with showcase kiosk; as long as they don't reload the page, the results should stay in console.log, right?